# How can I loop this a certain number of times? (js)

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I'd like to repeat a certain text N amount of times. This N would be any number, and I'd input it at the last line, on multip("", N). In this case, N = 3.

However, it just doesn't work. The point is to get a function to receive a text and a number of repetitions, making it repeat the text N times and stop afterwards, but I can't, and I just don't know what's wrong.

```js
function multip(text, repetitions) {
    let counter = repetitions;
    while(counter < repetitions) {
        counter++;
    }
    
    return text + "lalala";
}

multip("", 3);
```

Comment: Why will the condition `while(counter < repetitions)` return true if `counter = repetitions`?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's alright to do, but I declared in the function that the counter would get a +1 everytime the function ran; my goal with the counter = repetitions part was to associate these two elements to each other.

Also to be honest I'm not sure about what I'm doing

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```js
function multip(text, repetitions) {
    let counter = 0;
    let res = ''
    while(counter < repetitions) {
        res += text;
        counter++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

```js
multip('la',3);//lalala
```

```js
function multip(text, repetitions) {
    let counter = 0;
    let res = ''
    while(counter < repetitions) {
        res += text;
        counter++;
    }
    return res;
}
console.log(multip('la',3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a simpler solution is. Just use the string's native `.repeat()` function.

```js
console.log("HelloWorld".repeat(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `for` cycle and concatenation `+=` of string

```js
function multip(text, repetitions) {
  let string = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) string += text;
  return string
}

const concatenateString = multip('la', 3);

console.log(concatenateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

When the "number of times" is known in advance, the loop to use is a `for` loop:

```js
function multip(text, repetitions) {
  for (let i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
    console.log(text + "lalala");
  }
}

multip("", 3);
```

`while` loops are to be used when you don't know in advance how many times you're going to run the loop.

Comment: Maybe I know the reason... your question has a function returning something, my answer doesn't account for that. If your goal is indeed to have that behaviour, the answer from AlTheLazyMonkey is the one to consider, using a `for` string and returning the concatenated value.  Other answers for now do the trick but using a `for` loop is indicated in this case, and the repeat() while working is probably less versatile if you want to go any further than just repeat a string...

Comment: In the truth I downvote your answer because I understood that @Elysa wanted a function that return a string with inside repeated N times the input string, but after I read again the question, that it's a little bit ambiguous, I upvoted your answer for compense the unknown downvoter too. Sorry my fault.

Comment: No harm done, it's really not about the downvote, more about what I can improve in my answer. To be honest after re-reading the question trying to understand the downvote I realized I indeed may not be answering fully, but my point was mainly to insist on `for` loops answering exactly the title of the question :-)

Comment: Sorry if my question was ambiguous, I'm new to JS so I don't really know how to accurately phrase what I had trouble with. Thanks everyone for the help though :)